# Using excel to organize an alphanumeric list

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, drive-letter, numbering

How do I get the following list in order alphabetically, and then by numerical values on an excel sheet? CV1, CV2, CX1, CX10, CX2, CX3, CX20, CX4, CX30.

Final order should be: CV1, CV2, CX1, CX2, CX3, CX4, CX10, CX20, CX30, CV1, CV2

Comment: the number must have the same number of digits ie.: `CV01`,`CV02` and so on.  or you will need to parse the string into two helper columns one with the letters the other with numbers and sort on those.

Comment: In my opinion, you can try to add auxiliary columns to split text and number, then based on the text column and number column to sort data.

Answer (score 1):

Place your values in column A.

Column B contains:

`=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))`

Column C contains

`=LEFT(A1,B1-1)`

Column D contains:

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-B1+1)`

Then, select all the columns and do a multi-sort on columns C and D.